# How I can cache jquery ui tabs data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I am rendering a usercontrol on tab select using ajax.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: { cache: true },
        spinner: 'Loading ...',
        cache: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var text = $(ui.tab).text();

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "abc.aspx/GetData",
                    data: "{'tabType':'" + text + "'}",
                    cache: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                           $('#tabsResult').html(response.d);
                          },
                    failure: function(msg) {

                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

how can I prevent the tab from loading the remote content again on each tab click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way is to use a flag to let the tab knows if it has been loaded. For example, use $('#tabsResult').html().

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: { cache: true },
        spinner: 'Loading ...',
        cache: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var text = $(ui.tab).text();
            if(!$('#tabsResult').html())
            {
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "abc.aspx/GetData",
                    data: "{'tabType':'" + text + "'}",
                    cache: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                           $('#tabsResult').html(response.d);
                          },
                    failure: function(msg) {

                    }
                });
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if you want to stop the ajax load period or only if the content changes.  Below is an example that will load only the content is new, otherwise just replace with a JS `var` that checks whether the function has been called before with no hashing:

You could hash the result and store that local, check against that in your success handler:

[JavaScript MD5](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/)

```
var __lastHash = "";
$("#tabs").tabs({
    ajaxOptions: { cache: true },
    spinner: 'Loading ...',
    cache: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var text = $(ui.tab).text();
        __lastHash = MD5Hash(test); //call a hashing API, 
                              //several to choose from, see link above  
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "abc.aspx/GetData",
                data: "{'tabType':'" + text + "'}",
                cache: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                        if(__lastHash != MD5Hash(response)) //load if different
                        { 
                            $('#tabsResult').html(response.d);
                        }
                      },
                failure: function(msg) {

                }
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load tab content only once - then I'd suggest you include it in the HTML right away, instead of loading it via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used jQueryUI tabs with the jQueryUI Ajax stuff, I use MS Ajax to load update Panels which are the panes of the tab control. So my suggestion may not help directly and I can't easily check that for you. However...

jQueryUI tabs *already have a flag* which tells you if the tab has been loaded. The flags are on the DIV of each tab, with status "false", "loaded", "loading", "error" etc. You can see it right there in the HTML, or pull it out with something like this below. I use these flags to re-mark tabs as "dirty" and stuff like that. The status is "loading" on 1st load of a tab, "loaded" there after.

```
show: function (event, ui) {
   var $target = $('#tabs > div:eq(' + ui.index + ')');
   console.log('tab id=' + $target.attr('id') + ' loaded=' + $target.attr('loaded'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like doing it this way, merely for readability of code.... you can switch on ui.index directly, but then you have to go and remember 'which index is XXX tab?'. This may be marginally slower, but improves code readability significantly in my opinion

```
tabM = $('#tabs-detail').tabs({
    'select': function (event, ui) {
      var tabId = $($('>ul li a', this)[ui.index]).attr('href');
      switch (tabId) {
        case '#tabs-detail-sales':
          //no action needed
          break;
        case '#tabs-detail-activities':
          //need to populate a table with related activities
          if ($('#table-activities tbody tr').length === 0) {
              //load code goes here
          }
       }
    }
});
```